# How can I over-write all rows in a CSV column with a new format?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv which contains multiple rows and I want to edit all the date items under the column titled: 'transaction.created'

The dates are currently formatted as follows:

'2017-09-23 12:10:11.603000+00:00'

To look like this:
'25/09/2017'

So far I have written a python script which does this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

def redate(x):
    day = x[8:10]
    month = x[5:7]
    year = x[:4]

    return '%s/%s/%s' %(day,month,year)

df = pd.read_csv('monzo_transactions.csv')
df = df[['transaction.amount', 'transaction.description', 'transaction.created']]

for i in df['transaction.created']:
    x = redate(i)
    df.set_value(i,'transaction.created',x)

df.to_csv('monzo_transactions_values_adjusted.csv')
```

But the new CSV file does not have the changes saved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with format from better explained [here](http://strftime.org/):

```
df = pd.read_csv('monzo_transactions.csv')
df = df[['transaction.amount', 'transaction.description', 'transaction.created']]

df['transaction.created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['transaction.created']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

df.to_csv('monzo_transactions_values_adjusted.csv')
```

---

Also is possible use parameter `parse_dates` for convert 3.rd column to datetime (python counts from `0`, so use `2`) and `usecols` for filtering columns in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
cols = ['transaction.amount', 'transaction.description', 'transaction.created']
df = pd.read_csv('monzo_transactions.csv', parse_dates=[2], usecols=cols)

df['transaction.created'] = df['transaction.created'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

df.to_csv('monzo_transactions_values_adjusted.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Glad can help! Nice weekend!